# Formatação não funciona

Tags: php

Estou usando esta formatação para que o total me retorne o valor correto.
Porém esta linha me retorna sem os centavos. O valor tem que retornar por exemplo: 23,99  e está retornando 23,00.

Como resolver ?

```
$total = number_format($total,2, ',' , '.');
echo '<tr>
     <td colspan="5">TOTAL</td>
     <td><hr>  '.$total.'  </td>
     </tr>';
```

Comment: O `$total` tem que conteudo ?  Se for a questão de o decimal ser uma `,` então é duplicata de muitas outras que já tem aqui no site.

Comment: Este é o conteúdo de total:  $total    += number_format ($linha["unit"] * $qtd, 2, ',' , '.');

Comment: Inclua também o código anterior a esse. O que você postou até agora não tem como saber o problema.

Comment: Coloque um `var_dump($total); exit;` antes desse código e veja se `$total` realmente tem parte decimal.

Answer (score 0):

Se for só questão de máscara. Se o valor estiver sendo tratado corretamente (decimal ou double) use essa do jquery;

```js
Tem que colocar a referencia para :

jquery.maskMoney.min.js

$("#valor").maskMoney({
    prefix: "R$:",
    decimal: ",",
    thousands: "."
});
```

HTML:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="valor"  value="0" />
```

Comment: Eu entendo que sua intenção foi ajudar. Mas a pergunta referente ao `php`.